# Refactoring. Flip all (b != a) and (b == a) occurrences in code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have many occurrences in my code such as :

```
if (null != object)

and

if (null == object)
```

On a new work place I need to refactor these occurrences to:

```
if (object != null)

and

if (object == null)
```

For more readable code.

I tried to make a search and manually flip the occurrences but it was taking much time of me (Idea found more than 1000 occurrences of each case). I also have several similar constructions of my current code.

So my question is **how to FLIP ALL occurrences in all projects**? 

Is that possible do automatically or using macros?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/finding-and-replacing-text-in-file.html

Comment: @PM77-1 it's OK. But how i can set to replacing options object name?

Comment: In RegEx terms it's just a `word`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search and replace with regular expression like

```
if\s*\(\s*null\s*([\!\=]=)\s*(\w+)\s*\)
```

Replace with

```
if ($2 $1 null)
```

Comment: I use [Replace in Path](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/find-and-replace-in-path.html?search=replace%20in%20pa) feature, it works fine for me. Have you checked the "Regular expression" checkbox?

Comment: Edited the post, please try now.